# Android run dumpstate command without root permission

Tags: android

I am not able to run android dumpstate command with system and signature permission. I think only root can run the command, but we dont have su in the rom. How can I still get the root uid and run the dumpstate command.I have read that if I fork service from init.rc I will have the root uid, but I am not sure if I can do this or not.

Comment: I am not sure but this link might give some clue: http://tripoverit.blogspot.kr/2013/09/fix-for-android-phones-running-low-on.html

Comment: I am not looking to delete the logs but access them, and that too through an application

Comment: Using *#9900# you can run dumpslog also.

Comment: I am able to type *#9900# then in the display just click run dumpstate logcat.

Comment: How can do it programatically , i.e using java from an android application.